# Jquery Simplyscroll add left and right image in container / clip

Tags: jquery, css

I am using Jquery Simplyscroll (http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/) and I am looking for a method to add an image (faded png) on both left and right side in order to avoid my images being "cut off" once sliding by.

The code of my scroller:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <ul id="scroller">
      <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080608_9N3H5GYL_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
        <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080513_4D3SD1BQ_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li>
        <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080513_VPJWVQRW_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse bar"></li>
        <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_B1YJ08B6_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse chloe club fishtank"></li>
        <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse restaurant"></li>
        <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080608_38CG51J2_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
    </ul>
```

What would be the best practice/method in order for me to achieve this?

Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution :

```
    .mask {
         -webkit-mask: -webkit-linear-gradient(
              left,
             rgba(255,255,255,0),
             rgba(255,255,255,1) 5%,
             rgba(255,255,255,1) 95%,
             rgba(255,255,255,0)
         );
```